# how to find a particular string from a list of strings?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, core-data

I have to get a particular string from a list of strings using `NSPredicate (CoreData)`. For eg:
if I have the following array from `CoreData`

1. Helloworld
2. helloworld1234
3. helloworld 12345

from the above list I need only 1 and 3 one as result.
I have tried the following but i get all the three as result

```
NSPredicate *predicate =[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"contactName CONTAINS [c]%@",[arySeperator objectAtIndex:1]];
NSArray *filteredArray1 = [arrayContacts filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

To find all entries that contain the given text as a "whole word", you can use the
predicate "MATCHES" operator, which matches against a regular expression, and the
*word boundary* pattern `\b`:

```
NSString *searchWord = @"Helloworld";
NSString *pattern = [NSString stringWithFormat:@".*\\b%@\\b.*", searchWord];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"contactName MATCHES[c] %@", pattern];
```

This should also work if you add this predicate to the Core Data fetch request,
instead of filtering an already fetched array of managed objects.

Answer (score 0):

LIKE
The left hand expression equals the right-hand expression: ? and * are allowed as wildcard characters, where ? matches 1 character and * matches 0 or more characters.

```
NSString *textSearch = @"Raja";
NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"firstname LIKE '*%1$@*' OR lastname LIKE '*%1$@*'", textSearch];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to get if a string is present in an NSArray:

```
NSArray* yourArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"Str1", @"Str2", @"Str3", nil];
if ( [yourArray containsObject: yourStringToFind] ) {
    // do found
} else {
    // do not found
}
```